# Why doesn't my getter work?

Tags: php, getter

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

class Person {

   private $data;

   public function __construct($data) {
      $this->data = $data;
   }

   public function __get($prop) {
      return $this->data[$prop];
   }
}

$data = array('name' => 'Mark');
$person = new Person($data);
echo $person->get('name');

?>
```

Shouldn't this work?

I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Person::get()`, but I don't know why. As per the documentation for the magic methods, this code should work fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: There's no line in the manual that says $person->get() calls the __get() method :) Also, having to call get() would make the "magic method" definition pointless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
echo $person->name;
```

instead.

That's the magic of the __get magic method :-)

Just in case, you can define

```
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    echo $name;
    // do something useful
}
```

and then make magic calls like that:

```
$person->someMethod(); // echoes "someMethod"
```

Comment: I actually realized how stupid I was after I posted the question... I initially thought the correct call was `$person->getName()`, and when that didn't work, I got all discombobulated... Anyway, I have to wait 11 minutes before I accept your answer, but thank you.

Comment: Sure thing, updated my answer a little bit to add some explanation of  __call magic method.